# PHP - File Download in Android

Tags: php, android, download

I use a download handler to let the user access certain documents.
I've understood [Android has got some problems](http://www.digiblog.de/2011/04/android-and-the-download-file-headers/), so I made this script:

```
$result['title'] = "Test week";
$result['extension'] = "docx";
$file = '../database/'.$_GET['id'].'.'.$result['extension']; //The path to my file of which I am certain it exists, for example '../database/5.docx'

header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="DE '.$result['title'].'.'.strtoupper($result['extension']).'"');
readfile($file);
```

However, my old android phone still downloads the file as "File.bin" and the download fails, both symptoms of the source mentioned above. I only use two `GET` parameters, so now I'm really not sure what I've done wrong.

On other phones, the download works fine, so the actual `$file` path is correct.

Comment: Is a space in a filename a good idea?

Comment: What's `$android`, where is it set and is it set? Whats `$result` where is it set and is it set and an array? Whats `send_download()`where is it set, whats it do? Whats `$thefile` where is it set and is it set? Whats `$thefilename` where is it set and is it set?` Whats the error.log say? What what...

Comment: @greenapps it shouldn't be right? If I can't download a file with a space in the name, android is not that compatible.

Comment: @LozCheroneツ The used `$result` variables are explained in the comment lines, `$android` is set to true if the operating system is Android, `send_download()` is explained in the comment lines but irrelevant, so is `$thefile` as it's now only about the `if ($android)` section, as is `$thefilename` and where is the `error.log`? Be aware I do not have complete access to everything (possibly including that log) due to my hosting.

Comment: It's not the question if it's right but if it matters. Did you investigate?

Comment: @greenapps I understand. The updated script is now loaded, including the preset variables so every variable is known.

Comment: @greenapps I meant I updated my question and all variables are set there. (Just look at my new question xd)

Comment: If you address me then i expect you to have investigated and come with the results. No word.

Comment: @greenapps The variables do not need to be investigated for they're all set  beforehand as one can see in my question. Or could you be elucidative?

Comment: It was not me who talked about variables/parameters. I suggested that a space in a filename could be problematic. So I asked you to investigate without the space in: `filename="DE '`. Now did you?

Comment: @greenapps now I did. I misunderstood. It did turn out to be the space. Thank you. Would you like to post this as an answer? You will gain reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use spaces in filenames or replace them with %20. Url encode.